# Java swing: implementing my Comboboxmodel for JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, combobox

I need my combo box to have short names of organizations. The problem is i **can** see organizations names in dropdown list, but **cant** actually select it. Where is my mistake?

```
public class ToComboBoxModel extends AbstractListModel implements ComboBoxModel {
      private String selectedItem;

      private List<Organization> orgs;

      public ToComboBoxModel(List orgs) {
        this.orgs = orgs;
      }

        @Override
      public String getSelectedItem() {

        return selectedItem;
      }

        @Override
      public void setSelectedItem(Object newValue) {
            for (Organization o: orgs){
                if (newValue==o){
                    selectedItem=o.getShortName();
                    break;
                }
            }
      }

        @Override
      public int getSize() {
        return orgs.size();
      }

        @Override
      public String getElementAt(int i) {
        return orgs.get(i).getShortName();
      }
    }
```

Setting model:

```
query =session.createQuery("from Organization where isMain = 0");
List orgs=query.list();
toComboBox.setModel(new ToComboBoxModel(orgs));
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect it's that your `setSelectedItem()` method compares objects using `==` rather than `.equals()`

Consider using a [DefaultComboBoxModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultComboBoxModel.html) which already implements useful methods.

**Edit**:
Also according to the Docs you should be calling all registered `ListDataListener` objects when setSelected is called.

Using a `DefaultComboBoxModel` is fairly straightforward. You create a new `DefaultComboBoxModel` add the elements you want it to contain then call `getSelectedItem()` to retrieve the element that is currently selected.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I used equals(), problem persists. Could you, please, provide an example of DefaultComboBoxModel? I think the problem in my code not the stuff i extend.