# assign keys for combo box in java

Tags: java, swing, awt, jcombobox

I want to add a `JComboBox` in Swing that is simple but I want to assign the values for each items in combo.   I have the following code

```
    JComboBox jc1= new JComboBox();
    jc1.addItem("a");
    jc1.addItem("b");
    jc1.addItem("c");
```

Now what I want is that when click on combo box it should return  1, 2 and 3 correspondingly 
 instead of a ,b, c.
Is there any way to assign the key values for each items in combo box?

Comment: a, b & c can be represented as 1, 2 & 3 by `JComboBox.getSelectedIndex()+1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add an item as an object instead of adding String like this:

```
JComboBox<ItemClass> jc = new JComboBox<ItemClass>();
    jc.addItem(item1);
    jc.addItem(item2);
    jc.addItem(item3);
```

So to return key, the function of the event is : `jc.getSelectedItem().getKey`
Doing this way you have to override the `toString()` function of class ItemClass to return the  string you want to show in combobox.

Btw, for return number, you may try : `jc.getSelectedIndex()`, it'll return your index of your string (`0 1 2` for `"a" "b" "c"`)

Comment: JComboBox is not a Generic class. so you can't directly use above code. instead you need to define a custom ComboBoxModel and set it in JComboBox object.

Comment: It is still JDK 1.7 .... http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html

Comment: but how and where i have to assign the key

Comment: getKey() is a public member of ItemClass, constructor looks like ItemClass( int key, String text ), attributes stores parameters and getKey() { return key; }

Comment: @Taiki, you are right. my mistake. plz edit your response so that i can change my vote.

Comment: how to create object of item1, item2,item3 in ItemClass plz give the example thanks in advance

Comment: Actually ItemClass is your own class to store the items in combobox, it can contains properties like key or value to store the value for your purpose. Because JComboBox in JDK 1.7 now support generic, it works like a List<T>, so you can use JComboBox<String> to store a list of String items, or JComboBox<Your-Own-Class> to store the value, and use jc.getSelectedItem() to get your object to return any property you want.

Comment: @taiki your idea is good, I would add the ItemClass deceleration so it more obvious to other reads that ItemClass isn't meant to represent a class from the Java API

Comment: You'll also need to supply a ListCellRenderer to properly render the value in the combobox

Comment: -1 for _have to override the toString() function of class ItemClass_ which is wrong: see the comment by @MadProgrammer for the correct way

Answer (score 1):

you can create your own Model and add it to the combo box instead of adding Strings directly.

check Java [ComboBoxModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/ComboBoxModel.html).

you can find more info in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8254940/java-swing-implementing-my-comboboxmodel-for-jcombobox)

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your data in a simple class:

```
class MyData {
  int value;
  String text;
  ...
}
```

Now you can write your own renderer by extending BasicComboBoxRenderer. Cast the "value" to "MyData" and render the text.

```
public class Bla extends BasicComboBoxRenderer{

@Override
public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value,
        int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
    if(value instanceof MyData) {
        setText(((MyData) value).getText());
    }
    return super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected,
            cellHasFocus);
}
}
```

if you use Java7 it is best practice to use generics like @Taiki has shown. Now you can get the selected object by jc.getSelectedItem(). It is always from type MyData and you can access the text ("a", "b", etc.) and the value (1, 2, 3, etc.)