# Add items on Jcombo Box

Tags: java, swing, events, awt, jcombobox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [assign keys for combo box in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12870859/assign-keys-for-combo-box-in-java)

I am using `JComboBox` control in a Swing application. I have to add employee code and his name on `JComboBox` but i want to display only  employee name not the code.
but when i select the employee name it should return the corresponding employee code.
what is the best and easy  solution for it. 
I am using the following code for adding the items on `JComboBox`

```
  try       
   {   
     JComboBox jc1= new JComboBox();
     jc1.addItem("X");
     jc1.addItem("Y");
     jc1.addItem("Z");  

    }

   public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent ie)
   {
      String code=(String)jc1.getSelectedItem();
       //while items being selected it should return the emp code of the given emp name 
        //eg if user selects X it should return the emp code corresponding to X. 

    }
```

Comment: Also, stop putting greetings (_Dear stackoverflow..._) and stuffs like "plz help", "Thanks", etc... They are cluttering your question and make it looks like you are begging us... See the answer to [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts#answer-3021)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of adding the code to the JComboBox, you have to add the Employee object (with the two members). Then you have to create a custom ListCellRenderer (extending DefaultListCellRenderer) to render the employee name.

Take a look at [Oracle's tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#renderer).