# how to populate JCombobox with data from JPA

Tags: jpa, jcombobox

How can i populate the Jcombobox with the data from my jpa list? Desperate help needed

`public static MyNames myNames() {
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("JavaTrialsPU");
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        Query q = em.createNamedQuery("MyNames.findAll");
        MyNames n = (MyNames) q.getResultList();
        return n;
    }`

```
public static void myCombo() {        
    comboBox = new JComboBox(????--how can i make the jcombobox display my myNames() list--?????);
    frame.add(comboBox, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Try to populate a JComboBox with objects. Then try to load objects from the database using JPA. Then combine both.

Comment: you can create combobox model 
try the following link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8254940/java-swing-implementing-my-comboboxmodel-for-jcombobox

Answer (score 0):

you can use jcombox method

```
comboBox.addItems();
```